# C++ vector of strings, pointers to functions, and the resulting frustration

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am a first year computer science student, for on of my final projects, I need to write a   program that takes a vector of strings, and applies various functions to these. Unfortunately, I am really confused on how to use pointer to pass the vector from function to function. Below is some sample code to give an idea of what I am talking about. I also get an error message when I try to deference any pointer.

thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string>::pointer function_1(vector<string>::pointer ptr);
void function_2(vector<string>::pointer ptr);


int main()
{
   vector<string>::pointer ptr;
   vector<string> svector;

   ptr = &svector[0];

   function_1(ptr);
   function_2(ptr);
}

vector<string>::pointer function_1(vector<string>::pointer ptr)
{
   string line;

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       cout << "enter some input ! \n"; // i need to be able to pass a reference of the vector
       getline(cin, line);              // through various functions, and have the results 
      *ptr.pushback(line);             // reflectedin main(). But I cannot use member functions  
   }                                      // of vector with a deferenced pointer.

   return(ptr);
 }

 void function_2(vector<string>::pointer ptr)
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       cout << *ptr[i] << endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you clarify your requirements a bit? It sounds to me like you're trying to apply a series of transforms to each element in one vector to generate an entirely new vector with the result.  If this is case, one of the easier ways would be to compose a functor chain of the various transforms and then simply use `std::transform` to perform the actual transformation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::pointer` is not `std::vector<T>*`, it is `T*`.

Don't worry about using pointers; just use references, e.g.,

```
void function_1(std::vector<string>& vec) { /* ... */ }
```

`function_2`, which does not modify the vector, should take a const reference:

```
void function_2(const std::vector<string>& vec) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Pretty much this. When you receive a std::vector<string>&, then the name that you give that reference is considered to be a literal synonym. They exhibit pretty much the same syntax as if you took the variable by value (except the &), but the semantics of pointers.

Comment: This is the right answer. Don’t use pointers unless it’s not possible to use references.

Comment: I'm going to try this one, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make "vector::pointer" = "vector*"

Also note that there are other issues, not having to do with your question, such as "*ptr.pushback(line)" actually meaning something completely different from what you think.  That should be "ptr->pushback(line)".

Comment: not counting the fact that pushback doesn't exist and that it's actually push_back. But like James said using references will make your headaches go away.

Comment: yeah, sorry I didn't check over it before I posted.